# MethodHandles.filterArguments() example gives an exception

Tags: java, methodhandle

With Java `1.8.0_92`, on trying to run the example of MethodHandles.[filterArguments()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.html#filterArguments-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-int-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle...-), the following exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: expected (String,String)String but found (String,String)Object
        at java.lang.invoke.Invokers.newWrongMethodTypeException(Invokers.java:298)
        at java.lang.invoke.Invokers.checkExactType(Invokers.java:309)
        at SomeTest.main(SomeTest.java:15)
```

The code is:

```
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.filterArguments;
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.lookup;
import static java.lang.invoke.MethodType.methodType;

import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;

public class SomeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        MethodHandle cat = lookup().findVirtual(String.class,
                "concat", methodType(String.class, String.class));
        MethodHandle upcase = lookup().findVirtual(String.class,
                "toUpperCase", methodType(String.class));
        System.out.println(cat.invokeExact("x", "y"));
        MethodHandle f0 = filterArguments(cat, 0, upcase);
        System.out.println(f0.invokeExact("x", "y")); // Xy
        MethodHandle f1 = filterArguments(cat, 1, upcase);
        System.out.println(f1.invokeExact("x", "y")); // xY
        MethodHandle f2 = filterArguments(cat, 0, upcase, upcase);
        System.out.println(f2.invokeExact("x", "y")); // XY
    }
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Some informations from doc about invokeExact:Invokes the method handle, allowing any caller type descriptor, but requiring an exact type match.
     * The symbolic type descriptor at the call site of {@code invokeExact} must
     * exactly match this method handle's {@link #type type}.
     * No conversions are allowed on arguments or return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `invoke()` instead of `invokeExact()` here, if you using `invokeExact()`, you should add cast to result type, like `(String) invokeExact()`.